# How to move Azure Storage blob to other container using Java SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, azure-java-sdk

I'm trying to move blob from one container to another with in the same storage account. I'm using Java SDK for it.

My code:

```
StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential("accountname", "accountkey");
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint("storageaccountendpoint").credential(credential).buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient =  blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("failed");
        BlobClient dst = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("https://xxxstorage.blob.core.windows.net/success/");
        BlobClient src = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("https://xxxstorage.blob.core.windows.net/failed/Graphs.jpeg");
        dst.beginCopy(src.getBlobUrl(), null);
```

I have to move the blob from failed container to success container. But I'm facing 500 internal server error.

What can I try next?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written so far and the issues you are running into. Also if you search for this thing, I am pretty sure that you will find plenty code samples for that.

Comment: Updated the code in the above question

Comment: What's the issue you are running into with your code.

Comment: Updated the code.. I'm facing the specified blob does not exist error . What should be given as the src blob path and dest blob path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason for getting the error is that you are specifying blob URL instead of blob name when creating `BlobClient`. Also, you were not creating a `BlobContainerClient` for the source container.

Please try by changing your code to:

```
StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential("accountname", "accountkey");
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint("storageaccountendpoint").credential(credential).buildClient();
BlobContainerClient sourceBlobContainerClient =  blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("success");
BlobContainerClient destinationBlobContainerClient =  blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("failed");
BlobClient dst = sourceBlobContainerClient.getBlobClient("Graphs.jpeg");
BlobClient src = destinationBlobContainerClient.getBlobClient("Graphs.jpeg");
dst.beginCopy(src.getBlobUrl(), null);
```

Do note that I have created a new `BlobContainerClient` for the source blob container.

Comment: Hi Gaurav .. I'm able to copy the blob from one container to another. But the source container still contains the blob. Ideally it should be deleted right incase of move operation.

Comment: Again I need to delete the blob from source container. For this I need to do one more operation. Is there any possibility by using single operation perform the move operation

Comment: There is no native move operation. You will need to delete the blob by performing the delete operation on destination blob after the copy operation is completed.

Comment: Hi Gaurav ..  I have posted one question. Can you please look into this URL ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73868237/how-to-read-tags-of-an-azure-resource-using-java-sdk