# How to read tags of an azure resource using java sdk?

Tags: java, azure

I have some tags (like environment, subscriptionId, clientId e.t.c.,) added to my eventhub. I need to list those tags using java sdk from an azure resource(eventhub)?

I can see the below link which uses a http endpoint to list the tags of a specific subscription.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/list

But I need to fetch the list of tags of a specific resource using java sdk. How to read those tags using java sdk from an azure resource?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the `GenericResource` instance of the resource you need using one of the [get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.resources.models.genericresources?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-resourcemanager-resources-models-genericresources-get(java-lang-string-java-lang-string-java-lang-string-java-lang-string)) methods and then call the [`tags()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.resources.fluentcore.arm.models.resource?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-resourcemanager-resources-fluentcore-arm-models-resource-tags()) method on it.